# Designer.cs Errors

Tags: asp.net

I'm very new to ASP.net,  and I had to fix a issue in and ascx file (It was just an html fix).  When I got ready to put the code back into the repository I checked the changes in the Designer.cs file. They don't seem to match up with the changes in the ascx file.

Ultimately where do I see the errors for designer files?  Will I see them when I build?  When I view the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an interesting question with multiple scenarios. Assuming in your markup you have `<asp:Label ID="Label2"` but in Designer.cs you have `protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label Label1;`:

### Scenario #1

You do not access Label1 or Label2 anywhere else.

No errors will happen.

### Scenario #2

You set `Label1.Text = "Test"` in the code-behind file, or you set some control attribute to Label1 (such as

You get a runtime exception.

### Scenario #3

You set `Label2.Text = "Test"` in the code-behind file.

You get a build error.

Comment: So only time you would get an error with the designer.cs file is if you are trying to access the variables via the corresponding cs file?

Comment: I think so. It's point is to provide instance variables you can access in the cs file.